# Kartik Gridview responsive column headers

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

[image]

In Kartik Gridview is there a way I can move the Column Headers and Column Search Fields so they are next to each other than stacked like this when when on an Iphone etc.

I want it to show FAQ Type - Question - Answer all on one line when I am see this on a Iphone 6 screen

Comment: have you tried add responsive table in gridview?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'responsive'=>true,
```

Your gridview:

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;

// Generate a bootstrap responsive striped table with row highlighted on hover
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true
]);
```

[Refrence](http://demos.krajee.com/grid)